# how can i add padding to my gif image using wand library python

Tags: python, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif, wand

Right now i am creating a blank background image and compositing the original image over the blank image to give effect of padding. but it is returning only a single frame after composite function.

```
   with Image(width=required_width, height=new_height+margin, 
       background=value) as padded_img:
                padded_img.composite(img, top=margin//2)
                padded_img.save(filename='mypath')
```

the image i am getting in return is not gif image(the image is not animated and only one frame is showing) how can i composite gif images such that i get all of my frames or is there any alternative to this.

Comment: See sequence at https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.12/guide/sequence.html. For example:  `for frame in img.sequence:`.  Also you can add padding by using either extent or border.